# Cloud9 Mysql importing .tsv into table

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have sports watch data which measures heart rate, calories, strides taken etc.

I have created a database and table in cloud9 and was wondering if there is a way to import the .tsv data. I also have a copy of the raw data as .txt saved on cloud9 if that is easier to work with?

I am new with sql and its my 1st year in university could use some help with this as I don't understand a method on how to do it.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'all_project_database/MeanMachine/data/data_all.tsv' INTO TABLE Patients;
```

ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/all_project_database/MeanMachine/data/data_all.tsv' (Errcode: 2)

any help is much appreciated,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has a command LOAD DATA INFILE:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loading-tables.html

It should be able to solve your problem.

UPDATE: to correct the error, you need a slash in your file path:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/all_project_database/MeanMachine/data/data_all.tsv' INTO TABLE Patients;
```

assuming you do have a file at that location. To check if you do:

```
ls -l /all_project_database/MeanMachine/data/data_all.tsv
```

Comment: Do you have any personal experience with cloud9 ide by any chance? I cant get this working

Answer (score 1):

I moved the .tsv file into the mysql directory and it the code worked! Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to find its location, cd in it and load file then.
You may try to use something like this:

```
> filedir=`sudo find . -type f -name 'data_all.tsv' |sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#'` &&\
cd $file &&\
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data_all.tsv' INTO TABLE Patients;
```